# Android geofences not triggering properly

Tags: android, geolocation, geofencing, android-geofence

I've created a few geofences around the same location like you can see on the image. Technically, I should receive four **Entered** transitions. But I only receive transition from one of the four fences.(which varies from time to time) What might be the reason? Is it too dense? I'm using a BroadcastReceiver to receive the transitions and it works fine. But not accurate. Any opinion about this behavior is highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: 1. You have more than 4 circular indicators, how many in total. 2. What does your traversal path look like? 3. And how long/num of location updates did you wait after entry did the various fences fail to trigger.

Comment: @MorrisonChang 1] I have 6 fences. Current location is within 4 of those. But I only receive a transition from one of them(random). Then if I move the mock location, sometimes the other fences trigger.2]These are around my home which I go by walk and one is along the train line.  3] Location update interval is 30 minutes.

Comment: The current location is inside 4 fences. Then, why only one random fence is triggering? This is what I'm failing to understand.

Comment: What radius are you using?